# Angular: Child route refresh issue

Tags: angular

I am using child route in my Angular application. When I do direct refresh on child path, the style.css is getting loaded on parent path instead of root. This is causing the page to loose global styling as style.css is not found on root. Its working perfectly when navigating with angular routing, but issue happens only I do browser refresh on child route.

The above issue is not reproducible in local, but happening only when I deploy angular application in AWS cloud-front. I have tried all possible fixes like setting base href, etc.. but no luck

Comment: Have you tried setting the "useHash" property in the router settings to true?

Comment: Hi Derek, you saved my day. The useHash strategy done the trick and its ideal for single page application. Thank you very much. Kind Regards, Shaheer

Comment: No problem Shaheer!